# How to upload image and the text in a textbox without using any form using jquery on click using ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**View code**

```
    <input type="text" id="txtImageName"></input>
    <input type="text" id="txtImageDescription"></input>
    <input type="file" id="txtImageName"></input>
    <input type="button" id="btnUpload" Value="Upload">
```

**Jquery Code**

```
<script>
        $('#btnUpload').click(function () {       
                var file = $("#txtImageName").get(0).files;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: "@Url.Action("HomeAddNew", "Admin")",
                    data:
                    {
                        ImageName: $('#txtImageNameoption').val(),
                        ImageDescription:$('#txtImageDescription').val(),                   
                        Image: file
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('hai');
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
        });
    </script>
```

**Controller code**

```
public ActionResult HomeAddNew(string ImageName, string ImageDescription, HttpPostedFileBase Image)
        {
            //in the above HttpPostedFilebase I'm getting the null value but, I don't want to use .fileupload method or formdata class in jquery. 
            return View();
        }
```

**Explanation**: Whenever I check the file in controller method it is showing as `null`. Please send me the perfect solution for this. It will help me a lot. My email id is ganesh@concai.co.uk

Comment: why do you want to do this without a form?

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload a file with ajax. If your browser requirements starts from `IE10`then you can use `xhr`.

Code and information about how you should do it [HERE](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/uploading-file-using-xmlhttprequest-level-2/).

Also, there's a plugin called `FileAPI`, which you can find [HERE](https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI)

**Simple demo with `progress bar`**

```
function startUpload() {
var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");

if (fileInput.files.length == 0) {
    alert("Please choose a file");
    return;
}

var progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
    progressBar.value = percentComplete;
};

xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        alert("Sucess! Upload completed");
    } else {
        alert("Error! Upload failed");
    }
};
xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert("Error! Upload failed. Can not connect to server.");
};

progressBar.value = 0;
xhr.open("POST", "ajax-upload", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", fileInput.files[0].type);
xhr.send(fileInput.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .but my scenario is, i do have the another text coming from the textboxes .so i need to send even that text using ajax post so if i use file upload control i cannot send the text attached  with that it;s may be my illusion if you have any solution for this that would help e a lot i was trying to do this almost from a week i didnt find any answer.please reply me back with the answer.

Comment: i am doing this task in asp.net mvc

Comment: i think you can send an object to server. try it.  xhr.send({file: fileInput.files[0], text:' your text '});. Or add to your files[0] a new property called 'text'